# How can I use a non-caching infinite lazy list in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Infinite lazy lists are awesome!

```
> my @fibo = 0, 1, *+* ... *;
> say @fibo[1000];
43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
```

They automatically cache their values, which is handy ... most of the time.
But when working with huge Fibonacci numbers ([example](https://projecteuler.net/problem=104)), this can cause memory issues.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to create a non-caching Fibonacci sequence.  Anyone?

Comment: http://examples.perl6.org/categories/euler/prob104-moritz.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Zaid.  My eventual solution is [here](http://pastebin.com/xAs727Ux).  It should be a lot faster than the one from Moritz, since I just keep track of the last 9 and first 14 digits of the Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One major problem is you are storing it in an array, which of course keeps all of its values.

The next problem is a little more subtle, the [dotty sequence generator syntax `LIST, CODE ... END`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-..._operators) doesn't know how many of the previous values the *`CODE`* part is going to ask for, so it keeps all of them.
( It could look at the arity/count of the *`CODE`*, but it doesn't currently seem to from experiments at the REPL )

Then there is the problem that using [`&postcircumfix:<[ ]>`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#postcircumfix_%5B_%5D) on a [Seq](https://docs.raku.org/type/Seq) calls [`.cache`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/cache) on the assumption that you are going to ask for another value at some point.
( From looking at the source for Seq.AT-POS )

It's possible that a future implementation could be better at each of these drawbacks.

---

You could create the sequence using a different feature to get around the current limitations of the dotty sequence generator syntax.

```perl6
sub fibonacci-seq (){
  gather {
    take my $a = 0;
    take my $b = 1;

    loop {
      take my $c = $a + $b;
      $a = $b;
      $b = $c;
    }
  }.lazy
}
```

If you are just iterating through the values you can just use it as is.

```perl6
my $v;
for fibonacci-seq() {
  if $_ > 1000 {
    $v = $_;
    last;
  }
}
say $v;

my $count = 100000;
for fibonacci-seq() {
  if $count-- <= 0 {
    $v = $_;
    last;
  }
}
say chars $v; # 20899
```

---

You could also use the [Iterator](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterator) directly. Though this isn't necessary in most circumstances.

```perl6
sub fibonacci ( UInt $n ) {
  # have to get a new iterator each time this is called
  my \iterator = fibonacci-seq().iterator;
  for ^$n {
    return Nil if iterator.pull-one =:= IterationEnd;
  }
  my \result = iterator.pull-one;
  result =:= IterationEnd ?? Nil !! result
}
```

If you have a recent enough version of Rakudo you can use [`skip-at-least-pull-one`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/skip-at-least-pull-one).

```perl6
sub fibonacci ( UInt $n ) {
  # have to get a new iterator each time this is called
  my \result = fibonacci-seq().iterator.skip-at-least-pull-one($n);
  result =:= IterationEnd ?? Nil !! result
}
```

---

You can also implement the [Iterator](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterator) class directly, wrapping it in a [Seq](https://docs.raku.org/type/Seq).
( this is largely how methods that return sequences are written in the Rakudo core )

```perl6
sub fibonacci-seq2 () {
  Seq.new:

  class :: does Iterator {

    has Int $!a = 0;
    has Int $!b = 1;

    method pull-one {
      my $current = $!a;
      my $c = $!a + $!b;
      $!a = $!b;
      $!b = $c;
      $current;
    }

    # indicate that this should never be eagerly iterated
    # which is recommended on infinite generators
    method is-lazy ( --> True ) {}

  }.new
}
```

Comment: Another great answer. "the dotty sequence generator ... [caches results] ... &postcircumfix:<[ ]> on a Seq calls [caches results]". What do @Larry say are the downsides to relying on use of an `@` sigil or an *explicit* `.cache` to indicate that caching is desired?

Comment: (Am I right that, if the rules were that you only got caching if you used an `@` sigil or explicitly called `.cache`, then the answer to this SO question would be the trivial and elegant change to `my $fibo = 0, 1, *+* ... *; say $fibo[1000];`?)

Comment: "*doesn't know how many of the previous values the CODE part is going to ask for, so it keeps all of them*" -- Wait, what?? If the second part is true, that's IMO pretty bad and deserves a bug report. I also disagree with the first part, that it *can't* know how many elements to remember: It just has to look at the signature of the lambda, the way `.sort` and `.map` look at the signature of the lambda they're passed and adapt their behavior accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation and examples.  Looks like there is no convenient way to do what I wanted.  I [ended up](http://pastebin.com/xAs727Ux) just old-fashionedly iterating myself in-place, that was the easiest (but not so Perl 6 cool) way to do it.

Comment: @raiph I looked at Seq.AT-POS and it calls `.cache`. Whether it should or not is another question, and I can see arguments for both.

Comment: @smls I was going to mention that it could be smarter, but that could have made it less clear. All I know is that using that syntax on the REPL kept increasing the memory footprint without it ever going back down.

Comment: @BradGilbert Fwiw I asked about this and [lizmat answered on #perl6-dev](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6-dev/2017-01-16#i_13926565). I appreciated lizmat answering, and appreciate the enormous amount of great work she does, but I hate the answer (which I interpret as something like "yes, having just `@` and explicit `.cache` do caching would be cool, and I tried to make it that way but couldn't get it to work").

Comment: I'm late to the party, but this answer is referenced in the [bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=126189#ticket-history) for the memory leak. RE: *doesn't know how many of the previous values the CODE part is going to ask for*; that's not true, it can look at arity to figure it out. The brief examination shows it's a memory leak in continuations so likely it's not meant to cache-everything-by-design.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, a noob cannot comment.

When defining a lazy iterator such as sub fibonacci-seq2, one should mark the iterator as lazy by adding a "is-lazy" method that returns True, e.g.:

```
method is-lazy(--> True) { }
```

This will allow the system to detect possible infiniloops better.

Comment: In general you need at least 100 rep to comment. You can always comment if you asked the question though.

Comment: If you made a smaller post, and flagged a moderator to make it a comment, they could have done that for you.